# How to put a "<" inside Text component, React Native

Tags: react-native, text

I think there's an easy way to solve it, but I can't find it anywhere. I'm trying to put a "<" character inside a Text component, and it gives me a Syntax Error, with an Unexpected token message. How to solve it?

Code example:
`<Text> Sample Text with Syntax Error <3 </Text>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "&lt ;" in place of <(less than symbol) without space before semicolon. for other other you can refer to below link to get useful entity name:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp